# Package mirroring: Are there similar packages to ttf-mscorefonts-installer in the archives?

Tags: apt, package-management, apt-mirror

## Scenario:

You set up a local mirror for an environment where clients/servers should only use this internal mirror server and then all of sudden packages like `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`([1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/ttf-mscorefonts-installer), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography)) want to download content from Sourceforge, which—depending on who ever owns Sourceforge at the time—is suboptimal at best.

## Question:

- Are there more packages like this, one should know about preferably before setting up a "mirror"?

  - How to get a list of these?
  - What can be done for or against such cases?

Answer (score 0):

While I was searching for more names—flashplugin-installer and some other *-installer packages—I found that these packages depend on `wget`. Obviously.

So I ran the following command with this result (alphabetically sorted) on a 20.04 installation:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-enhances wget | grep -v wget:i386
wget
Reverse Depends:
  abcde
  abi-monitor
  apf-firewall
  apt-mirror
  bladerf-firmware-fx3
  bladerf-fpga-hostedx115
  bladerf-fpga-hostedx40
  bladerf-fpga-hostedxa4
  bladerf-fpga-hostedxa9
  cloud-image-utils
  cltl
  cpanminus
  cpl-plugin-amber-calib
  cpl-plugin-fors-calib
  cpl-plugin-giraf-calib
  cpl-plugin-hawki-calib
  cpl-plugin-muse-calib
  cpl-plugin-naco-calib
  cpl-plugin-uves-calib
  cpl-plugin-vimos-calib
  cpl-plugin-visir-calib
  cpl-plugin-xshoo-calib
  dahdi-dkms
  debian-cd
  debootstrap
  diaspora-installer
  dillo
 |di-netboot-assistant
  disc-cover
  dphys-config
  ebook-speaker
  firehol-tools
  firmware-b43-installer
  firmware-b43legacy-installer
  firmware-microbit-micropython-dl
  flashplugin-installer
  fonts-mathematica
 |foomatic-db-engine
  freedombox
  geographiclib-tools
 |gkrellweather
  google-android-build-tools-17-installer
  google-android-build-tools-18-installer
  google-android-build-tools-19-installer
  google-android-build-tools-20-installer
  google-android-build-tools-21-installer
  google-android-build-tools-22-installer
  google-android-build-tools-23-installer
  google-android-build-tools-24-installer
  google-android-m2repository-installer
  google-android-ndk-installer
  google-android-platform-10-installer
  google-android-platform-11-installer
  google-android-platform-12-installer
  google-android-platform-13-installer
  google-android-platform-14-installer
  google-android-platform-15-installer
  google-android-platform-16-installer
  google-android-platform-17-installer
  google-android-platform-18-installer
  google-android-platform-19-installer
  google-android-platform-20-installer
  google-android-platform-21-installer
  google-android-platform-22-installer
  google-android-platform-23-installer
  google-android-platform-24-installer
  google-android-platform-2-installer
  google-android-platform-3-installer
  google-android-platform-4-installer
  google-android-platform-5-installer
  google-android-platform-6-installer
  google-android-platform-7-installer
  google-android-platform-8-installer
  google-android-platform-9-installer
  google-android-sdk-docs-installer
  googleearth-package
  hplip
  hyperspec
 |ieee-data
  jigdo-file
  kinect-audio-setup
  ktoblzcheck
  libcupt4-2-downloadmethod-wget
 |libdvd-pkg
  libskypat-dev
  luarocks
  maas-enlist
 |megadown
  mythtv-backend
 |opam
  openrocket
 |origami
  osmctools
  pcb-rnd-cloud
  pepperflashplugin-nonfree
  perl6-zef
  perlbrew
  plait
  playonlinux
  podget
  pokemmo-installer
  primesense-nite-nonfree
  prism2-usb-firmware-installer
  publicfile-installer
  python3-curtin
  quake3-data
  rfcdiff
  rinse
  rocksndiamonds
  rrdweather
  runescape
  screenbin
  sdic-gene95
  simple-cdd
  snmp-mibs-downloader
  ssh-import-id
  susv2
  susv3
  susv4
  svn-buildpackage
  ubiquity
  ubuntu-standard
  virtualbox-ext-pack
 |winetricks
  wmfrog
 |wsl
  zomg
```

To avoid installing a package I pin them on the client machine, like so:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/restricted-extras-blacklist
Package: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Pin: origin *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

One could inspect every of those packages listed above, some are just fine like `ubuntu-standard`, identify external sources and mirror these too if required or just block them.

Answer (score 0):

"*-installer" packages often indicate non-free software.

(Free software can be packaged directly. It doesn't need an "installer" or a EULA.)

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu :

> The four main repositories are:
>
> 1. Main - Canonical-supported free and open-source software.
> 2. Universe - Community-maintained free and open-source software.
> 3. Restricted - Proprietary drivers for devices.
> 4. Multiverse - Software restricted by copyright or legal issues.

Non-free software is generally confined to the 'restricted' and 'multiverse' pockets of the Ubuntu repositories.

If you don't want to distribute non-free software on your mirror, one option is to simply exclude multiverse.

If you don't want non-free software on a specific system, it's trivial to remove multiverse from apt sources.

Comment: Non-free software was not my primary concern, but that's another way to think about it. Disabling multiverse removes a few of these efficiently and probably a few id did not get by looking for reverse dependencies of wget, but I'm not sure about the remaining ones. I'll keep it in mind and keep searching.